# React Material-Table: Typing lag outside of table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I'm using material-table to display a table, with table data being retrieved by calling an api and storing in a state hook. I also have a hidden modal that is opened via material-table's add button full of input fields, where each input field has an associate state variable in the overall component, to be used to add new rows.

My issue is when I type into an input field in the modal, there is a noticeable delay between typing and the change rendering - especially if I mash the buttons.

It appears that Material-Table re-renders itself or checks if anything in the table changes with every change to an input and is the cause of the lag.

The issue can be reduced to the below code structure (it seems to occur if input is associated with a state variable).

```
const component = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const [var, setVar] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(// Call API and set data, []);

  return (
    <div>
         <MaterialTable></MaterialTable> 
         <input value={var} onChange={x => setVar(x.target.value)}></input>
    </div>)
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a solution to my lag issue or is material-table designed this way?

**Edit.** Included sandbox. Typing really fast in the input has a noticeable lag.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-yjbpr?file=/src/App.js

**Edit 2.** Updated sandbox with CEich's solution. There appears to be a noticeable lag if you hold backspace/hold a key.
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-2-8g98l?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you put that in a sandbox so we can take a look?

Comment: I've included a sandbox!

Answer (score 0):

Try using useCallback

```js
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import MaterialTable from "material-table";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const handleChange = useCallback((e) => {setName(e.target.value)}, [setName])
  const table = (
    <MaterialTable
      columns={[
        { title: "First Name", field: "Name" },
        { title: "Surname", field: "Surname" }
      ]}
      data={[{ Name: "John", Surname: "Doe" }]}
      title="Title"
    />
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello {name}</h1>
      <div>
        <label>Type here fast -> </label>
        <input value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
      </div>
      {table}
    </div>
  );
}
```

By putting the callback code directly in the jsx, you were causing the component to re-render every time the value changed.

useCallback keeps your handler the same unless something in the provided array changes. (Here, that's only the `setName` method). Two different functions are never considered equal, even if they have the same function body. So, when comparing your callback function, react would cause your component to re-render on every keystroke. For a smaller component, this probably might not make a difference. But for a more complex component, the issue is more obvious

Comment: Thanks @CEich! Really appreciate the explanation as well, I have much more to learn!

Comment: Hi @CEich! I used your solution and there is a noticeable improvement, thank you! But there is still a lag if I hold a key such as holding backspace which appears to be due to re-rendering. Is this type of lag inevitable?